# How to insert text from file into new XML tags

Tags: python, xml, xml-parsing, elementtree

I have the following code to try to parse an XML file such that it reads from external text files (if found) and inserts its contents into newly introduced tags and saves a new XML file with the resultant manipulations.

The code looks like this:

```
try:
    import xml.etree.cElementTree as ET
except ImportError:
    import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import os

# define our data file
data_file = 'test2_of_2016-09-19.xml'

tree = ET.ElementTree(file=data_file)
root = tree.getroot()

for element in root:
    if element.find('File_directory') is not None:
        directory = element.find('File_directory').text
    if element.find('Introduction') is not None:
        introduction = element.find('Introduction').text
    if element.find('Directions') is not None:
        directions = element.find('Directions').text

for element in root:
    if element.find('File_directory') is not None:
        if element.find('Introduction') is not None:
            intro_tree = directory+introduction
            with open(intro_tree, 'r') as f:
                intro_text = f.read()
            f.closed
            intro_body = ET.SubElement(element,'Introduction_Body')
            intro_body.text = intro_text
        if element.find('Directions') is not None:
            directions_tree = directory+directions
            with open(directions_tree, 'r') as f:
                directions_text = f.read()
            f.closed
            directions_body = ET.SubElement(element,'Directions_Body')
            directions_body.text = directions_text

tree.write('new_' + data_file)
```

The problem is that it seems like the last found instance of file_directory, introduction, and directions is saved and spread out to multiple entries, which is not desired as each entry has its own individual record so to speak.

The source XML file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Root xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <Row>
        <Entry_No>1</Entry_No>
        <Waterfall_Name>Bridalveil Fall</Waterfall_Name>
        <File_directory>./waterfall_writeups/1_Bridalveil_Fall/</File_directory>
        <Introduction>introduction-bridalveil-fall.html</Introduction>
        <Directions>directions-bridalveil-fall.html</Directions>
    </Row>
    <Row>
        <Entry_No>52</Entry_No>
        <Waterfall_Name>Switzer Falls</Waterfall_Name>
        <File_directory>./waterfall_writeups/52_Switzer_Falls/</File_directory>
        <Introduction>introduction-switzer-falls.html</Introduction>
        <Directions>directions-switzer-falls.html</Directions>
    </Row>
</Root>
```

The desired output XML should look like this:

```
<Root xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <Row>
        <Entry_No>1</Entry_No>
        <Waterfall_Name>Bridalveil Fall</Waterfall_Name>
        <File_directory>./waterfall_writeups/1_Bridalveil_Fall/</File_directory>
        <Introduction>introduction-bridalveil-fall.html</Introduction>
        <Directions>directions-bridalveil-fall.html</Directions>
        <Introduction_Body>Text from ./waterfall_writeups/1_Bridalveil_Fall/introduction-bridalveil-fall.html</Introduction_Body>
        <Directions_Body>Text from ./waterfall_writeups/1_Bridalveil_Fall/directions-bridalveil-fall.html</Directions_Body>
    </Row>
    <Row>
        <Entry_No>52</Entry_No>
        <Waterfall_Name>Switzer Falls</Waterfall_Name>
        <File_directory>./waterfall_writeups/52_Switzer_Falls/</File_directory>
        <Introduction>introduction-switzer-falls.html</Introduction>
        <Directions>directions-switzer-falls.html</Directions>
        <Introduction_Body>Text from ./waterfall_writeups/52_Switzer_Falls/introduction-switzer-falls.html</Introduction_Body>
        <Directions_Body>Text from ./waterfall_writeups/52_Switzer_Falls/directions-switzer-falls.html</Directions_Body>
    </Row>
</Root>
```

But what I end up getting is:

```
<Root xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <Row>
        <Entry_No>1</Entry_No>
        <Waterfall_Name>Bridalveil Fall</Waterfall_Name>
        <File_directory>./waterfall_writeups/1_Bridalveil_Fall/</File_directory>
        <Introduction>introduction-bridalveil-fall.html</Introduction>
        <Directions>directions-bridalveil-fall.html</Directions>
        <Introduction_Body>Text from ./waterfall_writeups/52_Switzer_Falls/introduction-switzer-falls.html</Introduction_Body>
        <Directions_Body>Text from ./waterfall_writeups/52_Switzer_Falls/directions-switzer-falls.html</Directions_Body>
    </Row>
    <Row>
        <Entry_No>52</Entry_No>
        <Waterfall_Name>Switzer Falls</Waterfall_Name>
        <File_directory>./waterfall_writeups/52_Switzer_Falls/</File_directory>
        <Introduction>introduction-switzer-falls.html</Introduction>
        <Directions>directions-switzer-falls.html</Directions>
        <Introduction_Body>Text from ./waterfall_writeups/52_Switzer_Falls/introduction-switzer-falls.html</Introduction_Body>
        <Directions_Body>Text from ./waterfall_writeups/52_Switzer_Falls/directions-switzer-falls.html</Directions_Body>
    </Row>
</Root>
```

As an aside, is there any way to introduce the body tags' content without it all being printed on one line (for readability)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first `for` loop iterates over the `Row` elements of your document, assigning new values to your `directory`, `introduction`, and `directions` variables respectively, with each iteration, ending up with the values from the last occurring `Row` element.

What I would do is create a *dictionary* to map tag names to text contents, and then use that mapping to add the new sub-elements on the fly. Example (without reading the referenced files):

```
for row in root:
    elements = {}
    for node in row:
        elements[node.tag] = node.text

    directory = elements['File_directory']

    intro_tree = directory + elements['Introduction']
    intro_body = ET.SubElement(row, 'Introduction_Body')
    intro_body.text = 'Text from %s' % intro_tree

    directions_tree = directory + elements['Directions']
    directions_body = ET.SubElement(row, 'Directions_Body')
    directions_body.text = 'Text from %s' % directions_tree
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  It turns out I found out what I did wrong and fixed it by rearranging how I did the loops, but creating a dictionary as you've suggested makes sense.